# unable to set uploaded file via frontend form as featured image

Tags: php

i have a form that allows input of name ,email & photo...when i click on submit i want it to insert a row into the posttype called'contact' with the info submitted by the form and the image as the featured image but **it does not set the image as featured image**

my code

```
<?php

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {    

     $yourname=$_POST['yourname'];
     $email=$_POST['email'];
     $myimage=$_POST['myimage'];    

$my_post = array(
 'post_title' => $youname, 
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'post_author' => 1,
 'post-thumbnails' => $myimage
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    $imageid = insert_attachment($file,$pid);    
    }
}
set_post_thumbnail($post_id,$imageid);
update_field( "field_5507c9", $email, $post_id );   
}   
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
         Your Name: <input type="text" name="yourname" value=""> <br>
         Your Email:  <input type="text" name="email" value=""> <br>
         Image: <input type="file" name="myimage" id=""><br>    
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />           
</form>
```

add this below to functions.php

```
function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {
    // check to make sure its a successful upload
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

    if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
    return $attach_id;
}
```

plus is there any way i can check if row is uploaded & echo a message if insert is done and then redirect to a new url after few seconds.

Comment: `insert_attachemnt` is not a WordPress function. It is `wp_insert_attachemnt`. [Read the documentation and try to use `wp_insert_attachemnt`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) (read carefully the parameters this function needs, they are not the same you are currently using).

Answer (score -1):

first of all you need to add enctype="multipart/form-data" to make your form support file uploads.

So far you've attached the image to the post, but you haven’t inserted them. Try something like this

```
<?php 
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' =>   null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID );  
$attachments = get_posts($args);  
if ($attachments) { 
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) { ?>

    <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title' , $attachment->post_title ); ?>

    <?php the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , false ); ?>

<?php }  
}
?>
```

Comment: Adding a code snippet and explaining why that is needed in the form would help the author more than just saying "do this".